# How to put DIVs in one line without changing their width?

Tags: html, css

There are much answers answers uning `float` or `overflow: hidden` or `display: inline-block`,  but they are **not appliable** for my problem, because of they all affect div width. So, please, avoid this answers and duplicate-marks.
here is my current page:

```css
  .scrollableWrapper {   
   overflow: auto;/*so if any of width changes apply, this won't work*/
  }
  .left {
   width: 30%;
   float: left;
  }
  .right {
   width: 70%;   
   float: right;
  }
  .all {
   border: 2px solid black;/*for visibility while developing*/
   width: 80%;
   overflow: hidden;
  }
```

```html
<div class="all">
 <div class="left">
  название
 </div>
 <div class="right">
  <div class="scrollableWrapper"><label>tezrnjetgnd;sngnsdlgnknsgfndlsngfklsngdngndksngnsngflsdgnklsnkgklsgnkldsngkndklsngklsdgnlsglksdngksnglnsldkgnksndgknsdklgsngnsdlgnknsgfndlsngfklsngdngndksngnsngflsdgnklsnkgklsgnkldsngkndklsngklsdgnlsglksdngksnglnsldkgnksndgknsdklgsngnsdlgnknsgfndlsngfklsngdngndksngnsngflsdgnklsnkgklsgnkldsngkndklsngklsdgnlsglksdngksnglnsldkgnksndgknsdklgsngnsdlgnknsgfndlsngfklsngdngndksngnsngflsdgnklsnkgklsgnkldsngkndklsngklsdgnlsglksdngksnglnsldkgnksndgknsdklg</label></div>
  <div>
   edit
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

And i need the edit text to be right afres scrollable, on the same line. Margin doesn't work.
P.S. I prefer to do it without recalculating width using jquery, but I know that it is possible (edit div has constant widht)

Comment: I have a hard time understanding your question Rephrase, please?

Comment: Its in one line only. Please elaborate the problem.

Comment: @designarti text `edit` and label with scroll should be on the same line, edit at the right of label, not under it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check if this working fiddel will help you

in your case  : https://jsfiddle.net/24ks85ue/1/

just change the `div` location and add `float left` for edit div class

Comment: That's exactly what i need, only i need to be it at the right, but it worked when i changed left to right. Only can you explain, please, why it works when edit div is first and not work when label is first?

Comment: the problem is not the label , the problem is the edit div is inside "scrollableWrapper" class which will take 295px width in tihs case due to the left div  take 126px in this case so the edit div will not find place to sitting

Comment: But it isn't in scrollableWrapper div, it is after it.

Comment: I still don't understand it's mechaniks, but ok. Let it work as it work, until it works.